# Using the line-profiler (in ipython) on compiled Cython code

Tags: python, cython, line-profiler

I read the answer to this question [How to profile cython functions line-by-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301931/how-to-profile-cython-functions-line-by-line), but I can't seem to get it to work with my setup.

I have a `cumsum.pyx` file:

```
# cython: profile=True
# cython: linetrace=True
# cython: binding=True
DEF CYTHON_TRACE = 1

def cumulative_sum(int n):
    cdef int s=0, i
    for i in range(n):
        s += i

    return s
```

I compiled it with:

```
cython cumsum.pyx
gcc cumsum.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs python3) -o cumsum.so -shared -fPIC
```

Then I tried to profile it in `ipython`:

```
%load_ext line_profiler
from cumsum import cumulative_sum
%lprun -f cumulative_sum cumulative_sum(100)
```

I don't get an error message, only an empty profile:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0 s
File: cumsum.pyx
Function: cumulative_sum at line 6

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     6                                           def cumulative_sum(int n):
     7                                               cdef int s=0, i
     8                                               for i in range(n):
     9                                                   s += i
    10                                           
    11                                               return s
```

How can I get this to work?

PS: I use CMake, not `setup.py`, so I would appreciate a build system agnostic solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that `DEF CYTHON_TRACE = 1` doesn't actually set the right constant.

Workarounds include:

1.
[MSeifert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41926480/6664393), using distutils

2.
Changing the gcc line to

```
gcc cumsum.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs python3) -o cumsum.so -shared -fPIC -DCYTHON_TRACE=1
```

3.
Making an extra header `trace.h` and setting the constant there

```
 #define CYTHON_TRACE 1
```

along with adding the following to `cumsum.pyx`

```
cdef extern from "trace.h":
    pass
```

4.
With CMake, adding

```
add_definitions(-DCYTHON_TRACE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation on Cythons "Profiling"](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/profiling_tutorial.html#enabling-line-tracing) already includes an example how to set the `CYTHON_TRACE` macro:

```
# distutils: define_macros=CYTHON_TRACE_NOGIL=1
```

instead of your `DEF CYTHON_TRACE = 1`.

It worked when I compiled it using `%%cython`:

```
%load_ext cython
%%cython

# cython: profile=True
# cython: linetrace=True
# cython: binding=True
# distutils: define_macros=CYTHON_TRACE_NOGIL=1

def cumulative_sum(int n):
    cdef int s=0, i
    for i in range(n):
        s += i
    return s
```

And showed the profiling:

```
%load_ext line_profiler
%lprun -f cumulative_sum cumulative_sum(100)
[...]
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     7                                           def cumulative_sum(int n):
     8         1            8      8.0      3.5      cdef int s=0, i
     9         1            3      3.0      1.3      for i in range(n):
    10       100          218      2.2     94.4          s += i
    11         1            2      2.0      0.9      return s
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Could you be more specific. What's wrong? Did you use `cythonize()`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, nothing changed from my original post, the profile comes up empty. Does it work for you if you "pre-compile" it?

Comment: Ah, maybe the distutils line doesn't do anything because I'm not using distutils

Comment: @user357269 Yes, the `# distutils :`-line is (as per documentation) only working if you use `cythonize`.