# line profiling Cython 0.25

Tags: python, cython, line-profiler

I am trying to line profile some code I wrote in Cython. But I cannot get it to work.

I have tried to follow all the steps given in [How to profile cython functions line-by-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301931/how-to-profile-cython-functions-line-by-line)

But I dont get any timings out as a result. What I done is posted here:

I am using python 3.6 and Cython 0.25.2

What I try to do:

First I run:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

In setup.py I have added:

```
import Cython.Compiler.Options

Cython.Compiler.Options.get_directive_defaults()['profile'] = True
Cython.Compiler.Options.get_directive_defaults()['linetrace'] = True
Cython.Compiler.Options.get_directive_defaults()['binding'] = True
```

and to the extension I added,

```
define_macros=[('CYTHON_TRACE', '1')]
```

In the script runMIcython.pyx, I have added:

```
@cython.profile(True)
@cython.linetrace(True)
@cython.binding(True)
```

In an ipython shell, I then try to run (takes about 1 min):

```
%load_ext line_profiler
import line_profiler 
import runMolecularIntegrals  
profile = line_profiler.LineProfiler(runMolecularIntegrals.runCythonIntegrals)
profile.runcall(runMolecularIntegrals.runIntegrals) 
profile.print_stats()
```

But the output I get is:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents  
==============================================================  
    10                                           cpdef 
runCythonIntegrals(int [:,:] basisidx, double [:,:] basisfloat, int [:,:] basisint, double[:,:] input, double[:,:] Na, double[:,:] S, double[:,:] T, double[:,:,:,:] ERI):
```

Comment: Have you found any solution by the end ?

Comment: @beesleep I am sorry, I never solved this.