# two dimensional array slicing in cython

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

I have a simple question, why this is not efficient:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as c_np

import cython
def function():
  cdef c_np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] A = np.random.random((10,10))
  cdef c_np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] slice

  slice = A[1,:]  #this line is marked as slow by the profiler cython -a
  return
```

How should I slice a numpy matrix in python without overhead.
In my code, A is an adjacency matrix, so the slices are the neighbours in my routing algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines marked by the annotator are only suggestions, not based on actual profiling. I think it uses a relatively simple heuristic, something like number of python api calls.  It also does not take into account the number of times something is called - yellow lines inside tight loops are much more important than something called once.

In this case, what you are doing is fairly efficient - one call to numpy to get the sliced array, and the assignment of that array to a buffer.

The generated C code looks like it may be better using the memoryview syntax which is functionally equivalent, but you would have to profile to know for sure if this is actually faster.

```
%%cython -a
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as c_np

import cython
def function():
  cdef double[:, :] A = np.random.random((10,10))
  cdef double[:] slice

  slice = A[1,:]
  return
```

Comment: I did this finally, no gain, less yellow in the html =P.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of repeating an already good answer (and not answering the question!), I'm going to point out a common misunderstanding with the annotator... Yellow indicates a lot of interacting with the python interpreter. That (and the code you see when expanded) is a really useful hint when optimizating.

*However!* To quote from the first paragraph in every document on code optimization ever:

> Profile first, then optimize. Seriously: don't guess, profile first.

And the annotations are definitely not a *profile*. Check out the cython docs on profiling and maybe this answer for line profiling [How to profile cython functions line-by-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301931/how-to-profile-cython-functions-line-by-line/)

As an example my code has some bright yellow where it calls some numpy functions on big arrays. There's actually very, very little room there for improvement* as that python interaction overhead is amortized over a lot of computation on those big arrays.

*I might be able to eek out a little by using the numpy C interface directly, but again, amortized over huge computation.