# Line profiling with cython in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cython, line-profiler

I'm trying to use liner_profiler library in jupyter notebook with cython function. It is working only halfway. The result I get only consist of first row of the function and no profiling results.

```
%%cython -a
# cython: linetrace=True
# cython: binding=True
# distutils: define_macros=CYTHON_TRACE_NOGIL=1
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import math


cpdef np.int64_t get_days(np.int64_t year, np.int64_t month):
    cdef np.ndarray months=np.array([31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31])
    if month==2:
        if (year%4==0 and year%100!=0) or (year%400==0):
            return 29
    return months[month-1]
```

For the profiling result int onlt shows one line of code

```
    Timer unit: 1e-07 s

Total time: 0.0015096 s
File: .ipython\cython\_cython_magic_0154a9feed9bbd6e4f23e57d73acf50f.pyx
Function: get_days at line 15

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    15                                           cpdef np.int64_t get_days(np.int64_t year, np.int64_t month):
```

Comment: Are you actually calling the function? It looks like the only thing you do is define the function hence only the `cpdef` line gets "run"

Comment: Yes I'm calling it in the next cell: `%lprun -f get_days get_days(2019,3)`

Comment: line profiler seems to have issues with cdef-functions (or cpdef). Not sure whether this is a problem of Cython or of the line_profiler.

Comment: This is also being tracked as issue ( https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler/issues/13 ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be seen as a bug in the `line_profiler` (if it is supposed to support Cython). To get the code of the profiled function, `line_profiler` [reads the `pyx`-file](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/blob/master/line_profiler.py#L210-L214) and tries to extract the code with help of `inspect.getblock`:

```py
...
# read pyx-file
all_lines = linecache.getlines(filename)
# try to extract body of the function strarting at start_lineno:
sublines = inspect.getblock(all_lines[start_lineno-1:])
...
```

However, `getblock` knows nothing about `cpdef`-function, as python has only `def`-functions and thus yields wrong function-body (i.e. only the signature).

**Workaround:**

A simple work around would be to introduce a dummy `def`-function, which would be a sentinel for the `cpdef`-function in such a way, that `inspect.getblock` would yield the whole body of the cpdef-function + body of the the sentinel function, i.e.:

```py
%%cython
...
cpdef np.int64_t get_days(np.int64_t year, np.int64_t month):
    ...

def get_days_sentinel():
    pass
```

and now the report `%lprun -f get_days get_days(2019,3)` looks as follows:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 1.7e-05 s
File: XXXX.pyx
Function: get_days at line 10

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    10                                           cpdef np.int64_t get_days(np.int64_t year, np.int64_t month):
    11         1         14.0     14.0     82.4      cdef np.ndarray months=np.array([31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31])
    12         1          1.0      1.0      5.9      if month==2:
    13                                                   if (year%4==0 and year%100!=0) or (year%400==0):
    14                                                       return 29
    15         1          2.0      2.0     11.8      return months[month-1]
    16                                           
    17                                           def get_days_sentinel():
    18                                               pass
```

There are still somewhat ugly trailing lines from the sentinel, but it is probably better as not seeing anything at all.