# Method to profile Cython functions line by line to get an output that shows time taken by both the python and c++ functions

Tags: python, c++, jupyter-notebook, cython

When I try to profile my python code in this manner I get an output where it shows the time taken by the python lines only and not the c++ lines. I am using '%prun -s'command to help profile these lines. The code is written in Jupyter Notebook.

```
from Cython.Compiler.Options import get_directive_defaults
directive_defaults = get_directive_defaults()

directive_defaults['linetrace'] = True
directive_defaults['binding'] = True

%load_ext cython
%%cython
# cython: profile=True

from pygpb import libgpb
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, color
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
import os 
import sys
from timeit import default_timer as timer

 def main(path):
    n_ori, Kmean_num, sigma_sm, sigma_lg = 8, 64, 2.0, np.sqrt(2)*2.0 
 
    # run it
    gpb = libgpb.Gpb()
    img = io.imread(path)
    if(img.strides[1] > 3):
        img = (255 * color.rgba2rgb(img)).astype(np.uint8)

    gpb.test_np_mat(img, img)

    # get texton
    texton = gpb.texton(img, n_ori,
                        Kmean_num,
                        sigma_sm, sigma_lg)
    start = timer();
    gpb_res, ucm_res = gpb.run(img)
    end = timer();
    print("Time taken by demo is : " ,end-start, "seconds") #time in seconds:

  [picture of the output][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlddP.jpg
```

Comment: You has no c++ lines art all, it unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: This is how line profiling can be used in ipython: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57563349/5769463, it will however not profile the c++ code, only cython.